# interator should return strings, not bytes

Tags: python-3.x

I found the following code on Stackoverflow.The coding makes the table "student" but nothing is populated. I get the following error:

***"ERROR:iterator should return strings, not bytes(did you open the file in text mode?)***

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import sqlite3

# Create the database
connection = sqlite3.connect('attendance5.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create the table
cursor.execute ('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS student')
cursor.execute ('CREATE TABLE student (StuID REAL, LastName TEXT, FirstName TEXT, Grade REAL, Address TEXT, Phone TEXT, Parent TEXT)')
connection.commit()

# Load the CSV file into CSV reader
csvfile = open ('attendance.csv','rb')
creader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

# Iterate through the CSV reader, inserting values into the database
for t in creader
   cursor.execute ('INSERT INTO student VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'t)

# Close the csv file, commit changes, and close the connection
csvfile.close()
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Does it have anything to do with the t in creader?

What am I doing wrong? Is it the creader t value? Thank you.

Comment: It is useful to post the entire stack trace and exception along with the message.  At a guess, though, I would say the error message is directing you to consider how the file is opened and ensure it returns strings, not bytes, when read.

Comment: The error-messages asks the correct question: "did you open the file in text mode?". No. You opened it in _byte_-mode. Just use `'r'` for your open-flag. (Also I recommend to read into the [`with`-statement](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement))